# per clock perf. - can I use different registers for same instruction?

Tags: performance, assembly, cpu-registers, clock

Can I use say four general purpose registers say r8,r9,r10,r11 each with MOV instruction for independent operations and be in impression that CPU is doing all those instructions in a single clock ?

I want to know because according to Agner Fog's Instruction Table, it says reciprocal throughput of MOV instruction is 0.25. It means CPU should be able to execute 4 MOV operations per cycle. Or I misinterpreted that all ??

I am a noob and have been learning Assembly in MASM since two months (mainly for learning debugging stuffs how registers works and it is really fun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit, just re-read your question, and you're asking about *different* registers.  I'll leave in my original answer; let's pretend your question wasn't just the most trivial case. :P

Yes, even without register renaming, these instructions can all execute (on separate execution units) in the same cycle because they're completely independent of each other.

```
mov   eax, 1
mov   ebx, ecx
mov   edx, [mem]
xor   esi,esi     ;xor-zero: doesn't even use an execution unit on SnB-family
```

This is the easiest case for superscalar execution.  If eax/rax was the destination for all four instructions, register-renaming would still allow all four instructions to execute in parallel.

Out-of-order execution allows four nearby instructions from separate dependency chains to execute at the same time, even if they weren't decoded or issued in the same clock cycle.  And they probably won't retire in the same cycle either, if there are instructions between them.  (The x86 ISA guarantees precise exceptions, like most other ISAs (ARM/PPC/etc.).  All current designs accomplish with in-order retirement.  So if a memory op segfaults, the program will stop at exactly that instruction, not just "well, there was a segfault somewhere recently, but we can't tell you where".  (That would be non-precise exceptions).)

Superscalar in-order designs like Atom, or P5 (original Pentium) can still take advantage of the parallelism in these four independent instructions, but not in many other cases.

In a hand-crafted loop, it's common for a SnB-family CPU to be able to sustain well over 3 fused-domain uops per cycle.  (It's also very easy to write loops that run at less than one fused-domain uop per cycle, due to latency, to say nothing of cache misses or branch mispredicts.)

---

Yes, multiple writes to the same architectural register can execute in parallel.  Register renaming is not a bottleneck on Intel or AMD designs.

To understand and make full use of Agner Fog's tables, you have to read [his microarch guide, or at least his "optimizing assembly" guide](http://agner.org/optimize/).  See also good stuff at the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki.

As Agner Fog's microarch pdf points out (section 9.8 about Intel SnB/IvB):

> Register renaming is controlled by the register alias table (RAT) and
>   the reorder buffer (ROB), shown in figure 6.1. The μops from the
>   decoders and the stack engine go to the RAT via a queue and then to
>   the ROB-read and the reservation station. The RAT can handle 4 μops
>   per clock cycle. **The RAT can rename four registers per clock cycle,
>   and it can even rename the same register four times in one clock
>   cycle.**

read-modify-write is another story (destination of an `add` instruction).  A read-modify-write of an architectural register is (part of) a dependency chain, while an unconditional `mov` or an xor-zeroing starts a new dep chain.  (Same for the output of certain other instructions like `lea` which don't read their destination).

Those register writes still rename the architectural register to a new physical register as well.  This is how CPUs handle cases like

```
mov eax, 1      ; start of a dep chain
mov [mem+rax+rcx], eax
inc eax         ; eax renamed again
```

The store needs the value of eax from before the `inc`.  It gets it because when it checks the RAT, the architectural eax is still pointing to the same physical register that the `mov eax,1` wrote.  The `inc` can't just modify that same physical register because it doesn't know what if anything is not done yet with the previous value of `eax`.